# Java Language Practice With Array

Tags: java

I had read some code in java but I can not understand the fifth line. What happened when a[c] - 'a'? Can anyone explain more clearly?
I just know that array first's elements are initialized with 0 then after while loop some of its element will be 1. 
Thanks for helping.

```
Arrays.fill(first,0);
char a[] = s1.toCharArray();// s1 is a string
int c=0;
while (c<a.length) {
    first[a[c]-'a']++;
    c++;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `s1`  ?

Comment: s1 is just a string , something like "adfgh" , "abcd"...

Comment: `a[c]-'a'` will take the character at index `c` and subtract the value of character `a` from it (which would be the decimal value 97) - so the result will be an integer which then is used as an index into `first`. This might cause an exception though if `s1` would contain uppercase letters or other characters with a smaller decimal value because that would result in a negative index (e.g. `'A'-'a'` would be -32).

Comment: `a[c]-'a'` is a very simple trick to represent assign numbers to alphabet letters. For 'a' it will produce 0, for 'b' it will be 1,  for 'e' it will be 4 and so on. All because arrays are indexed from 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot , now I understand , well , s1 is just contains lowercase letters  ascii[a-z] so it works.